# XAMPP nonstandard webhosting port

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, xampp, port80

I have Windows 7 and I've installed XAMPP. From what I've been told, you have to modify httpd.conf and enable port 80 publicly (along with portforwarding). Port 80 is blocked automatically by my ISP so I'm using port 81. This really isn't the problem, though. I have a Windows Vista desktop downstairs that has a different version of XAMPP, but the same port (81) and it runs fine. It was portforwarded and canyouseeme.org said it was online and working. Just to be sure, I asked a friend of mine to visit the website and he said it loaded. Now when I unportforwarded the Vista and portforwarded the Windows 7, there was the error. It was showed as offline, while I could connect via localhost. What is the problem? Should I downgrade to a lower build of XAMPP? Don't suggest downgrading unless its the absolute last available option.

The Windows 7 is also listening on port 81 and not 80. I went over that several times in httpd.conf. I might have edited another file in XAMPP which publicized port 81 and allowed it to be portforwarded. Any ideas on what this file could be, or what the issue is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This video will guide you through each of the steps for changing the default port on Windows 7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DWZ6Ecjl6I

Also, you may need to take propagation into consideration, sometimes when you make the switch it may not be visible right away...

Go through the steps in the video, make the switch and give it some time just in case propagation is an issue, if that still doesn't work post back here and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, the video gave me an idea as to what's wrong. I couldn't stop the mysql nor the apache services, so I had to force them off and force them back on to reload the httpd.conf file.